# Nokogiri v 1.8.1 issue when running Bundle Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

When running Bundle Install or Gem Install Nokogiri, I get the same issue which is preventing my app from running. I suspect this issue is local and came from moving everything up to Rails 5, but I'm not sure. Here is the error message:

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails_admin was resolved to 1.2.0, which depends on
    rails was resolved to 5.1.3, which depends on
      actioncable was resolved to 5.1.3, which depends on
        actionpack was resolved to 5.1.3, which depends on
          actionview was resolved to 5.1.3, which depends on
            rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
              nokogiri
```

(That comes from running Bundle Install)
I've tried running Bundle Update and using various Homebrew commands recommended by Github, but I haven't had any success.

gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.1'

```
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [xmlIO.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Comment: Have you tried running `brew doctor`? Might have to relink a few things.

Comment: Did you try running `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.1` ?

Comment: @Cyzanfar I just tried it, I updated the post with the error from that

Comment: OK run `gem update --system` then install xcode cl tools `xcode-select --install` and finally re run the gem installation `gem install nokogiri`. let me know if that helped

Comment: In my case this error started happening after installing a software update to xcode. @Cyzanfar your suggestion fixed the problem for me. Perhaps you could make that an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nokogiri fails to build normaly because you don't have dev libraries like libxml2. Look at the log file to see what happens or try to install libxml2 directly with `brew install libxml2`

See throubleshoting guide provided by Nokogiry at http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Comment: I have the dev version of `libxml2` installed its failing for me

Answer (score 13):

(for UBUNTU) First try to do this

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzmadev
```

then try to install.

Comment: This might have changed slightly since you wrote it, but what worked for me was:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev`

From the [official Nokogiri installation instructions](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)

Answer (score 13):

I'm just posting the solution I found (I had the same problem on MacOS). With this, the gem will be installed using the system libraries, which should solve the probleme you encountered.

1. If using **gem**:

```sh
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
 [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
 [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]
```

2. If using **bundle**:

```sh
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```

Comment: In my case 2. if using bundle works fine. Thank you for a solution.

Comment: You're very welcome, glad I could help someone out. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps that might help you solve this issue:

1. `gem update --system`
2. Install the Xcode command line tools: `xcode-select --install`
3. Finally now install Nokogiri: `gem install nokogiri`

Comment: happened to me after updating to ruby 3.5 - this fixed it.  but the command flags should be `--system` and `--install`

Comment: Go on then!  ;) :)

Answer (score 2):

On high sierra (and mojave), this worked for me

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/

bundle update

bundle install
```

Comment: This is gonna update the version of every gem in the Gemfile.

Answer (score 1):

libxml2 and **zlib** is required for building, you need to install both.

#### Fedora:

```
sudo dnf install libxml2-devel zlib-devel
```

#### Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: i have both libxml2 and zlib dev version its still failing for me

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue after I upgraded Xcode

I had to run: `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
then: sudo bundle install --system`

After that everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

If using MAC OS
You can try to

```
brew unlink xz
gem install nokogiri
brew link xz
```

I use MAC OS, and using `brew install ruby` to avoid messing up with the system's ruby environment, and the following `bundle install` goes very smoothly.